# How to search specific file format on the internet for download purpose

Tags: download, search, search-engines, file-format

For example : I want to search for specific file format (NES format) on internet to download.How to search to download from direct-link?

Answer (score 2):

Google lets you add "filetype:nes" to a search to restrict it to files with an extension of .nes.

Comment: This is right, but it's worth noting that a lot of fake download sites will simply re-map their file extensions to trick google.  This is sadly much less useful than it used to be.